# How to pass a value from href in HTML to Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, jquery, thymeleaf

I am trying to get info from a input bar and use the value for a modal. Currently I am using Thymeleaf  and I am getting everything mixed up. I tried setting the attribute for href using jQuery. Though I believe since the `th:href` gets rendered on page load, my code does not work.

The end goal is to send the info from the input field, process it in Thymeleaf, and then show the results in the modal. I can so far only accomplish it when I hard code everything. I am looking for a more dynamic way. Any help will be appreciated.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">

    <title>Application</title>

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/landing-page.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs ">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <!-- <a class="nav-link" href="create.html">Create</a> -->
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/addTyler">Create</a> 
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown ml-md-auto">
                     <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown">Account</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                         <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider">
                        </div> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Log out</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3 class="text-center">
                Taddm Mapping
            </h3>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row" id="search-row">  
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="filter-search">
            <input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">

            <div class="list-group" id="myList">
                <div th:each="plants : ${plants}">
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" th:text="${plants}"></a>
                </div>
            </div> 
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
            <a class="btn btn-primary eBtn">View</a> 
            <!-- <a th:href="@{findOne/(appcode=01G)}" class="btn btn-primary eBtn">View</a> -->
            </span>
        </div>

        <div class="myForm">
                <form th:action="@{/save}" method="POST">
                    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Update or Create</h5>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="appcode" class="col-form-label">AppCode:</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="appcode" name="appcode" value=""/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="save"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

    </div>

</div>



  </body>
</html>
```

**jQuery:**

```
// Empty JS for your own code to be here
$(document).ready(function() {




    $("#myList").toggle();

    $("#myInput").on("focus", function() {
      $("#myList").toggle();
    });

    $("#myInput").on("focusout", function() {
      // Here, it'll wait 100 miliseconds to hide the list.
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("#myList").toggle();
      }, 250);
    });

    $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
      var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

      $("#myList a").filter(function() {
        $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
      });
    });

    // This is the code to populate the field after selecting an option.
    $("#myList a").on("click", function() {
        var texto = $(this).text();
        $("#myInput").val(texto);
      });

    $(".eBtn").on("click", function(event){

        $("a").attr("href","@{findOne/(appcode='01G')}");       //Test


        event.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        console.log(href);

          $.get(href, function(appcode,status){
            $("#appcode").val(appcode);
          });

          $("#exampleModal").modal();

      });
  });
```

**Controller:**

```
        @RequestMapping("/findOne") 
        @ResponseBody
        public String findOne(String appcode) {
            System.out.println(mAppRepo.findById(appcode).get().getmAppName());
            return mAppRepo.findById(appcode).get().getmAppName();
        }
```